# Delaying slider animation and change effect to fade?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, fade

I am using a very simple JS for my slider, currently the images slide horizontally, left or right depending on which arrow you press. The problem I am experiencing is that there is no delay on the animation so if you click the direction arrows several times rapidly, it takes a while for the slides to catch up and there's a lot of strange overlapping.

I would like to change the animation effect to a fade and set up a delay so that you cannot advance to the next or previous slide until the current slide is done animating. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var slideInProgress = false; 
var currentSlideIndex = 0,
slides;
function setTopSlider(){
  if (jQuery('#top_slider #container .slide').length != 0) {
    slides = jQuery('#top_slider #container > .slide');
    for(var i=0; i <= slides.length; i++){
      jQuery(slides[i]).css('left','100%');
    };
    jQuery(slides[currentSlideIndex]).css('left','0%');

    var el=jQuery('.dot:eq('+currentSlideIndex+')');
    src = el.css("background-image").replace("_off", "_over");
    el.css("background-image", src);
    el.addClass('active');
  };
};

function slide(dir) {
    var current, next, nextSlide;
    current = jQuery(slides[currentSlideIndex]);
    if(!isNaN(dir)){
        next = dir;
        if(next > currentSlideIndex )dir = 'left';
        else dir = 'right';
    };


      if(dir == 'left'){
        if(!next){
           next = currentSlideIndex + 1;
           if(next >= slides.length){
              next = 0;
           }
        }
if (slideInProgress) {
    return;
    }
    slideInProgress = true;
        nextSlide = jQuery(slides[next]);
        nextSlide.css('left','100%');
        nextSlide.css('z-index',parseInt(current.css('z-index'), 10)+1);
        nextSlide.animate({left: '0%'}, 1500);
        current.animate({left: '-100%'}, 1500);
      }else{
        console.log('moving right');
        if(!next){
             next = currentSlideIndex - 1;
            if(next < 0){
              next = slides.length-1;
            }
        }
        nextSlide = jQuery(slides[next]);
        nextSlide.css('left','-100%');
        nextSlide.css('z-index',parseInt(current.css('z-index'), 10)+1);
        nextSlide.animate({left: '0%'}, 1500);
        current.animate({left: '100%'}, 1500);
omplete: function(){
            slideInProgress = false;
            });
      };

    current.addClass('active');
    nextSlide.removeClass('active');


    var el=jQuery('.dot:eq('+currentSlideIndex+')');
    src = el.css("background-image").replace("_over", "_off");
    el.css("background-image", src);
    el.removeClass('active');


    el=jQuery('.dot:eq('+next+')');
    src = el.css("background-image").replace("_off", "_over");
    el.css("background-image", src);
    el.addClass('active');



    console.log('currentSlideIndex'+currentSlideIndex);
    console.log('next'+next);
    console.log('dir'+dir);
    currentSlideIndex = next;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use some control variables.

Set some global (boolean) variable indicating that sliding is in progress and dont allow another sliding while previous is in progress.

**UPDATE:** I took your updated code, made some changes and marked changes I made in your code with // **** //. Hope, you will understand it :-). (I didnt test the code, but it should work).

```
// **** //
var slideInProgress = 0;
// **** //
var currentSlideIndex = 0,
        slides;
function setTopSlider() {
    if (jQuery('#top_slider #container .slide').length != 0) {
        slides = jQuery('#top_slider #container > .slide');
        for (var i = 0; i <= slides.length; i++) {
            jQuery(slides[i]).css('left', '100%');
        }
        ;
        jQuery(slides[currentSlideIndex]).css('left', '0%');
        var el = jQuery('.dot:eq(' + currentSlideIndex + ')');
        src = el.css("background-image").replace("_off", "_over");
        el.css("background-image", src);
        el.addClass('active');
    }
    ;
}
;
function slide(dir) {
    // **** //
    if (slideInProgress != 0) {
        return;
    }
    slideInProgress = 3;
    // **** //
    var current, next, nextSlide;
    current = jQuery(slides[currentSlideIndex]);
    if (!isNaN(dir)) {
        next = dir;
        if (next > currentSlideIndex)
            dir = 'left';
        else
            dir = 'right';
    }
    ;
    if (dir == 'left') {
        if (!next) {
            next = currentSlideIndex + 1;
            if (next >= slides.length) {
                next = 0;
            }
        }
        nextSlide = jQuery(slides[next]);
        nextSlide.css('left', '100%');
        nextSlide.css('z-index', parseInt(current.css('z-index'), 10) + 1);
        // **** //
        //nextSlide.animate({left: '0%'}, 1500);
        nextSlide.animate({
            left: '0%'
        }, {
            duration: 1500,
            complete: function() {
                slideInProgress--;
            }
        });
        //current.animate({left: '-100%'}, 1500);
        current.animate({
            left: '-100%'
        }, {
            duration: 1500,
            complete: function() {
                slideInProgress--;
            }
        });
        // **** //

    } else {
        console.log('moving right');
        if (!next) {
            next = currentSlideIndex - 1;
            if (next < 0) {
                next = slides.length - 1;
            }
        }
        nextSlide = jQuery(slides[next]);
        nextSlide.css('left', '-100%');
        nextSlide.css('z-index', parseInt(current.css('z-index'), 10) + 1);
        // **** //
        //nextSlide.animate({left: '0%'}, 1500);
        nextSlide.animate({
            left: '0%'
        }, {
            duration: 1500,
            complete: function() {
                slideInProgress--;
            }
        });
        //current.animate({left: '100%'}, 1500);
        current.animate({
            left: '100%'
        }, {
            duration: 1500,
            complete: function() {
                slideInProgress--;
            }
        });
        // **** //

    }
    current.addClass('active');
    nextSlide.removeClass('active');
    var el = jQuery('.dot:eq(' + currentSlideIndex + ')');
    src = el.css("background-image").replace("_over", "_off");
    el.css("background-image", src);
    el.removeClass('active');
    el = jQuery('.dot:eq(' + next + ')');
    src = el.css("background-image").replace("_off", "_over");
    el.css("background-image", src);
    el.addClass('active');
    console.log('currentSlideIndex' + currentSlideIndex);
    console.log('next' + next);
    console.log('dir' + dir);
    currentSlideIndex = next;
    // **** //
    slideInProgress--;
    // **** //
}
```

In [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) I used **complete** callback function, which sets `slideInPrgress` to false after animation completes.

Optionally, you can set another variable indicating that someone pressed arrow while previous animation was in progress and do that slide after previous finished.

Comment: what exactly didnt work? or, how does your updated code looked?

Comment: I'm not very good with javascript, I'm sure I misplaced parts of the code. Updated my original post. Thanks again!